# Blob is not a valid UTF-8 string error in test class though am converting base64 into normal text in apex class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, before-trigger, email2case, base64

Am getting case subject "?utf-8?b?QW5vbWFseSBkZXRIY3Rpb24g4oCTIERFIFNIQVc?="
In this format from third party system.
So am converting into string as below:

1. String s= case.subject;
2. String s1 = s.substring(10);
3. String s2= s1.removeEnd('?=');
4. Blob b= EncodingUtil.base64Decode(s2);
5. String finalText = b.toString();
6. Case.subject = finalText;

Test class:

```
Static testMethod void subjectDecoding(){
    
     Start test.startTest();
    
     Case c = new case();
     C.status = 'New';
     C.origin = 'Email';
     C.subject= '?utf-8?b? 
     QW5vbWFseSBkZXRIY3Rpb24g4oCTIERFIFNIQVc?=';
     C.RecordTypeId=schema.sobjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('query').getRecordTypeId();
    
    Insert c;
    Test.stoptest();
}
```

This is giving desired string output into case subject through(before insert in trigger) trigger handler class.
But when am writing test class and trying to insert case in that format am getting error as cannot insert and blob is not valid utf-8 format in the line 4/5 in the above code.

Please someone help in resolving the test class error

Comment: Can you include your test class in the question so the community can help you resolve the issue?

Comment: Added the test class. Please check but couldn't indent it

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a simple mistake just decrease the substring to 9 from 10. As it is missing the **Q**.

I tried to reproduce it and got the following output -

***Anomaly detHction – DE SHAW***

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was struggling with that issue..it worked great..

Comment: can you mark it as the best answer?

Comment: Sure will do, thanks